# Стоит ли переходить от swing к javaFX

Tags: swing, javafx

Стоит ли переходить от Swing к JavaFX? Требуются адекватные ответы. (Ответ что это "мамонт" меня не интересует.)

**Также есть ли в JavaFx менеджеры компоновки?**

**Какие отличия, преимущества?**

Comment: Ещё SWT забыли. Swing vs JavaFX vs SWT. Может кто-нибудь ещё вспомнит актуальный GUI. Я только про эти три слышал. Ну может ещё платформу Netbeans сюда приписать, хотя она вроде на swing-е базируется.

Comment: Я толком не знаю что такое SWT, приходилось пользоватся AWT, SWING

Comment: А Netbeans Platform ничего особенного не представляет как я понел.

Comment: Eclipse наверняка хотя бы на картинках видели? Сам на SWT нарисован и программки на SWT предлагает делать.

Comment: Кстати из всего перечисленного только на Netbeans Platforme и делал программку. Не сказал бы, что ничего не представляет. Он предлагает не разрозненные компоненты (они и так есть из того же Swing), а что-то вроде готового инфраструктурного базиса для приложения GUI. Довольно сложный в освоении для меня.

Comment: Еклипс я не использую, я использую netbeans, в котором есть только тотже swing, awt, javaFX и netbeans platform

Comment: Рано или поздно перейти придётся, если не обманывают на счёт его перспектив. Но лучше поздно, когда поправят как можно больше ошибок и главное компонентов наделают, не самом же их придумывать.

Answer (score 6):

Конечно стоит, т.к. Swing уже работает в профилактическом режиме. Долго ли его будут использовать в проектах, вот в чем вопрос. Раньше да, javafx была не очень, но сейчас вполне годный продукт. По сути, это тот же Swing, только доработанный, без костылей, позволяющий делать современные GUI, удобный интерфейс JavaFX Scene Builder позволяет делать морду не напрягаясь.
P.S: менеджеры компоновки в javafx присутствуют

```
Плюсы:
- современный продукт;
- поддержка со стороны Oracle и все плюсы связанные с этим (туториалы, доки и т.д.);
- быстрое создание морды;
- возможность использовать css стили;
Минусы:
- довольно молод;
- фреймворк еще разрабатывается;
```